# How to print multiple items of a JS object/array in per iteration with map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working in React. I am trying to find out a solution to a mapping problem. While mapping an object or array in javascript, we know it delivers one item of the array/ object in per iteration. For Example:

Consider an array of object like:

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    color: "black"
  }
];
```

Now,

```
items.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item.color}</p>)
```

This will show an output like :

```
red
blue
yellow
black
```

Now what if I want to bring multiple items in per iteration. For Example:

```
red blue
yellow black
```

How to do it ? Thanks in advance.
Please feel free to use this codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cloud-gnnye?file=/src/App.js:100-339

Comment: thats where the for loop shines vs map

Answer (score 2):

This action called "chunk" I would do:

```
import chunk from "lodash.chunk";

const colors = items.map(({ color }, i) => color);
const chunked = chunk(colors, 2);
const renderPairs = chunked.map(([first, second], i) => (
  <p key={i}>
    {first},{second}
  </p>
));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-forest-0pvvq?file=/src/App.js:86-679

[Lodash implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/chunk.js):

```
function chunk(array, size = 1) {
  size = Math.max(toInteger(size), 0)
  const length = array == null ? 0 : array.length
  if (!length || size < 1) {
    return []
  }
  let index = 0
  let resIndex = 0
  const result = new Array(Math.ceil(length / size))

  while (index < length) {
    result[resIndex++] = slice(array, index, (index += size))
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: Here is a simple implementation of `chunk`:  `function chunk(arr, size) { const chunks = []; for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));} return chunks;}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the second argument provided by `map` function which is the current index of the array to find the next item in the array and print accordingly.

You could see the working example here :- https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mccarthy-7fc3o?file=/src/App.js

```
   const iterate = items.map((item, i) => {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) return null;
  
      const next = items[i + 1] ? items[i + 1].color : "";
      return (
        <p key={i}>
          {item.color} {next}
        </p>
      );
    })
    // you could filter or not, it's up to you. React automatically discards null value
    .filter(x => x);
```

Comment: This will create overlapping pairs, whereas it seems OP doesn't want to repeat the array values.

Comment: Well, but it's iteration an item twice. How to make "red, blue" & "yellow,black" ?

Comment: @OsmanRafi I've updated the code to fit your needs. I don't think you need a library for chunking for a simple task, a simple `even` number check would do.